# Run Excel Macro from SSIS or Task Scheduler, without office installed on the server

Tags: excel, ssis, ms-office, vba

I have an excel with a couple of pivots and a Summary sheet. The excel has a macro which can refresh all pivots and send the contents of the Summary sheet in mail to some groups.

I want to automate the process with which we can call this macro on a daily basis.

Can I call this macro from Task scheduler or SSIS (on a server where Office is not installed?

Comment: No you can't run excel macros without excel installed. If you want to generate reports in excel there are other ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

No.  There is no way to run excel macros from a server without Office installed.

And even if you do install office it's a bad idea.  You could install office and then have an SSIS package with a .NET script task importing `Micrososft.Office.Interop.Excel` binaries and then use the `Run()` method execute a macro.  But please ....

**Don't do it**.

Microsoft [heavily discourages this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office).

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

Your best bet here is to re-engineer the macro.  Translate it to another language. What is it trying to do?  Is this something you could do by importing the excel data and using the PIVOT, UNPIVOT, and Send Mail tasks in SSIS?   Try those instead.   If that doesn't work, look into a script task that leverages the [EPPLus codeplex project](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to do heavy excel work on the server.  EPPlus will run a lot faster than `Interop.Excel`.

Good luck!